# How to: Hide the Ribbon in SharePoint 2010 Publishing Sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, ribbon

How to hide the Ribbon in SharePoint 2010 Publising site when the site is extended and map the to the public url.

When site is accessed on the public url site is asking the windows login authentication and after login the ribbon is visible and this is not the scenario for the publihsing sites.

Answer (score 1):

Ribbon can be hide by using following CSS style statement in Master page

```
.s4-ribbonrowhidetitle {
    display: none;
}
```

Use this [blog](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/07/ribbon-visibility-using-css/) to get more information